# Load multiple files from multiple folders in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am having a data set that contains multiple folders inside main folder and each folder contains multiple CSV files. Every CSV file has three columns named X,Y and Z. I want to create a dataframe so that first three columns of dataframe are three  X,Y,Z. I want two more columns such that fourth column contains name of folder from which CSV file is read. Fifth column contains the name of CSV file. How can I create this dataframe in Scala and Spark?

Comment: what did you try? How to load from CSV is in the Spark docs. And reagrding filename column, `.withColumn("filename", input_file_name)` is the way to go. How to get the directory out of it is obvious in Scala. Everything explained in the very good Spark docs. Alternatively, you could also use `wholeTextFiles` and then create the Dataframe manually

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use **`spark.read.csv`** then use **input_file_name** to get the filename and extract **directory** from the filename.

**`Example:`**

**`1.extracting directory from filename:`**

```
// Lets take we have directory `tmp2` with folders having csv files in it
tmp2
|-folder1
|-folder2

//extracting directory from filename

spark.read.option("header",true).
csv("tmp2/*").
withColumn("file_name",input_file_name()).
withColumn("directory",element_at(reverse(split(col("file_name"),"/")),2)).
show()

//+----+---+---------------------------+---------+
//|name|id |file_name                  |directory|
//+----+---+---------------------------+---------+
//|2   |b  |file:///tmp2/folder2/t1.csv|folder2  |
//|1   |a  |file:///tmp2/folder1/t.csv |folder1  |
//+----+---+---------------------------+---------+
```

---

**`2. Get folder name while reading file:`**

If you have folder structure like **`folder=<val>`** then spark reads folder as partition column and add `folder` as partition column.

```
//folder structure

tmp3
|-folder=1
|-folder=2

spark.read.
option("header",true).
csv("tmp3").\
withColumn("file_name",input_file_name()).
show(false)

//+----+---+------+---------------------------+
//|name|id |folder|file_name                  |
//+----+---+------+---------------------------+
//|a   |1  |2     |file:///tmp3/folder=2/t.txt|
//|a   |1  |1     |file:///tmp3/folder=1/t.txt|
//+----+---+------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: `input_file_name` throws error, replaced with `input_file_name()`, and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Follow up question -- is there way to just have directory name? without adding file name column?

Comment: Don't think there is inbuilt method exist for this.. but we can remove file name and get only directory name!

Comment: Found one possible way with `regex_extract` function: ```withColumn('dir', regexp_extract(input_file_name(), "([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+)/[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+\.csv", 1))```